# Change youtube API developer key for app transfer to another GooglePlay account?

Tags: android, youtube-api, google-play, transfer, android-youtube-api

I have an already published Android app which uses the youtube APIv3. This app shall be transferred to another Google Play dev account which I would own, too.

Do I have to change the youtube API developer key in the app source code? And do I have to make adjustments in the youtube dev account where I got the developer key etc.?

The app identifier/ package name as well as the app signing certificate would remain the same for future app updates. I would just have to change the Google Play developer account and transfer the app to the new account.

I suppose that it is not urgently necessary to make changes in the youtube API account or to change the developer key, but I would be interested in knowing your opinion.

Would look forward to feedback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Google Play developer account is unrelated to the account that you use to register for YouTube APIs.

Hence, **no, you do not have to change anything** (if you don't want to, of course).